# How can I become a monk in India?

Tags: advice

I am a lay person and I am from India. I wish to become a monk.
Other option before me is to go in search of Truth and reinvent the wheel and find enlightenment myself. But there is no place to go. There are no forests which are not under government control. People are materialistic and they hardly give any value to me becoming a monk or to the state of affairs of the world. That leaves me with only one choice and that is to become a monk.

How can I become a monk?

Comment: Better to investigate Vinaya and Philosophy the monastery follows, beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhistworld/ordination1.htm) provides an easy-to-read high level overview information on the [Ordination Procedure in the Theravada Tradition](https://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhistworld/ordination1.htm).

For details regarding the ordination, including eligibility etc., please see the Theravada [Vinaya section on Ordination](https://www.dhammatalks.org/vinaya/bmc/Section0054.html), translated by Ven. Thanissaro.

Please contact the [Maha Bodhi Society](https://mahabodhi.info/) for more information on how to become ordained in the Theravada tradition in India. They have many branches in India - please see the diagram below.

You can also try the [All India Bhikkhu Sangha](https://www.allindiabhikkhusangha.org.in/Centres_In_India_All_India_Bhikkhu_Sangha.aspx).

There are also many Tibetan Buddhist monasteries in India, like [Namdroling Monastery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namdroling_Monastery) in Mysuru etc.

[image: Maha Bodhi Society branches]

Answer (score 1):

It is generally believed by the Vinaya monks that ordaining in India is not good. I think it is because the Vast Majority of Indian Monasteries doesn't follow Vinaya or of invented traditions that follow a different Dhamma.

In Buddhism, Re-inventing any new ideas (as truths) either by ordaining as a solitary Hermit or ordaining in an Invented Tradition considered faulty, since the Omniscient One has already revealed the Truths. There is nothing to be revealed by others. The Disciples are only needed to follow the guidance that the Buddha has laid down.

Anyway, you can find some advice on Where to Ordain in following links, if you are looking for other options in other countries.

- [Vinaya Comparison of Monasteries](https://classicaltheravada.org/t/vinaya-comparison-of-monasteries/261)
- [Where to Ordain -American Buddhist Monk: Bhante Subhūti](https://americanmonk.org/where-to-ordain/)
- [Where to Ordain --philosophy matching - Dhamma Wheel](https://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=38243)

Answer (score 0):

You must search for an enlightened person and take initiation from him. Then you follow and execute your guru's instructions for advancement in spiritual life. That's what monks do.

Comment: Which guru ? Any specifics ?

Comment: @DheerajVerma, go and search for your teacher. They are preaching online.

Comment: No need to say that finding enlightened person (if any) is at least very difficult. It is considered that they can be accurately identified only by the Omniscient Buddha.